# How to import CSV into R not as Factors

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, types, factors

I have a large data set and I cannot manually assign variable types to each column. How do I get thousands of variables into R NOT as factors?

Maybe a loop with logic and error handling once the data is in to convert them into the correct data types?

Comment: add the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if you are using `read.csv`

Comment: How are you reading your files? `readr::read_table*` and `readr::read_csv*` do not do the automatic to-`factor` conversions. You can also always use `dplyr::mutate_if` to convert all `factor` columns to `character` vectors in one go; e.g. `... %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)`.

Comment: you may want to add `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to your ~/.Rprofile to make this the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`fread`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/fread) package:

```
data <- fread('example.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```